# Homework question: Represent function as power series

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

Represent the following function as a power series of powers of x-2.

$$f(x)=\frac{x-5}{3x^2+5x-2}$$

Now, the Taylor series got me thinking. Knowing my professor, she wouldn't have us solving huge derivatives like this one. So I'm wondering, is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: Start by using *partial fractions* to express your function in a nicer way.  And your instructor is nicer than I am, the denominator factors pleasantly.

Comment: After I just find the Taylor series for both partial fractions and the sum of those series is the representation of the original function?

Comment: @AndrejNaumovski Yes. If you're more familiar with power series around $0$, you can also do a translation before to reduce to that case (and shift back the result afterwards).

Comment: Yes, that's right. You will have to gather the two coefficients of $(x-2)^n$ into a single expression. And you will have to mention where your series converges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is another way of approaching this.

First, it will make things a bit easier to let $y=x-2$.

Then, write

$$\begin{align}
3x^2+5x-2&=(3x-1)(x+2)\\\\
&=(3(x-2)+5)((x-2)+4)\\\\
&=(3y+5)(y+4)
\end{align}$$

Next, using partial fraction expansion reveals that

$$\begin{align}
\frac{x-5}{3x^2+5x-2}&=\frac{y-3}{(3y+5)(y+4)}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{y+4}+\frac{-2}{3y+5} \tag 1
\end{align}$$

Now, we can expand each term of the right-hand side of $(1)$ separately.  For the first term, we have

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{y+4}&=\frac{1/4}{1+(y/4)}\\\\
&=\frac14\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-y/4)^n \tag 2
\end{align}$$

which is valid for $|y|<4$.

For the second term, we have

$$\begin{align}
\frac{-2}{3y+5}&=-\frac{2/5}{1+(3y/5)}\\\\
&=-\frac25 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-3y/5)^n \tag 3
\end{align}$$

which is valid for $|y|<5/3$.

Now, adding $(2)$ and $(3)$ yields

$$\begin{align}
\frac{y-3}{(3y+5)(y+4)}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{4^{n+1}}-\frac{2(3)^n}{5^{n+1}}\right)(-1)^ny^n
\end{align}$$

whereupon substituting back $y=x-2$ yields

$$\begin{align}
\frac{x-5}{3x^2+5x-2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\left(\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{n+1}-\frac23\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^{n+1}\right)(x-2)^n
\end{align}$$

where the series converges for $|x-2|<5/3$.

---

NOTE:

We can obtain a series representation for $|x-2|>5/3$ in terms of inverse powers of $x-2$.   That exercise is left to the reader.

Comment: And the interval of convergence for the original function would be the interval where both partial series converge, i.e $$-4<y<5/3$$?

Comment: @AndrejNaumovski Actually, we need to take the smaller interval of convergence.  Here that is $-\frac53<y<\frac53$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could factor the denominator and see what gives

Comment: The question is "... is there any other way to solve this?". I think this answer qualifies as an answer to that question.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I never quite understand the hasty use of the "down vote" by some users here.  I will neutralize inasmuch as your answer does address the OP's question.